# Add new VISA network device to resources

Tags: c#, visa

I'm setting up a test environment including several instruments connected via LAN(TCP/IP) or USB. A Software shall be written in **C#** using the `Ivi.Visa` library. The instruments (which will change over time) get their IP address from a DHCP server so they won't show up in the Resources discovered by`IVI.Visa.interop.ResourceManager.FindRsrc()` unless they've been previously added by the Keysight Connection manager Software (or equivalent NI tool).

`ResourceManager rMgr = new ResourceManager();
 string[] enumRcrs = rMgr.FindRsrc("?*INSTR");`

How does one achieve to discover new VISA Network devices in C# and add them to the resources list without having to use the external software before?

Answer (score 0):

Modern instruments may support discovery via mDNS (see LXI specification [here](https://lxistandard.org/Specifications/Specifications.aspx)). I'm not familiar with Ivi.Visa library, but you may want to look over its documentation for instrument discovery feature. If it is not supported then you can probably implement mDNS request in your C# code.